# How do I import seeds in countries that require a phytosanitary certificate?

Tags: seeds

Please note that this is not about shopping. More and more countries now require a phytosanitary certificate, which is a great hindrance to the acquisition of new plants, and I would like to know how to solve it.

I used to buy seeds abroad often, and recently my country requires a phytosanitary certificate for any quantity of seeds, but some seed stores don't offer it. Some plant species will be difficult to obtain if they cannot be purchased, because only few stores sell them and I have no other choice.

How should I get these seeds now and is there a phytosanitary agency service? Stores are usually located in the US, UK, Europe, China and some other countries. I heard some express or consolidation can do it, is that so? What other methods are available?

Comment: If I was going to research this, my first step would be to find the official government website that has information about the required phytosanitary certificate. So...what's the name of the country that has these requirements?

Comment: @csk As far as I know, most countries can apply for a phytosanitary certificate in almost the same way and know how to do it, but it needs to be obtained by the shipper and attached to the shipment being sent. Some seed stores do not do this. Such shipments cannot enter my country.

Comment: This seems to be a question that cannot be answered without more details like where you are and where you what country you want to buy from.  Even if you supplied those details regulations change and quickly become out of date.

Comment: Not sure about phytosanitary certificates, but even for a Small Lots of Seed permit, the rules could use some explanation. I mean, like how do you control whether they ship it through the required port of entry, for instance. I think they made these laws with corporations, and people who don't use the postal service, in mind.

Comment: @kevinskio If this is important then I am in Japan. the seed store could be anywhere, here assuming in Europe or US.
Our country requires a phytosanitary certificate and other countries can provide one, I don't see that changing in the future.

The important issue is that seed stores do not do this. I know how to apply for a phytosanitary certificate, but it is not possible to go to the other country to do so in person. I would like to know if there are other ways to obtain a phytosanitary certificate, such as the store giving the seeds to some agency service, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to contact the plant exporter company and ask them to help you process the phytosanitary certificate. To export, they need a permit to process export documents and a phytosanitary certificate.

As far as I know, [labijo](https://labijo.id/) is an Indonesian company that helped my friend get a phytosanitary certificate when they brought hand-carried plants from Bali, Indonesia. In Indonesia, processing phyto takes about 2 weeks. You need to send the plants to the company's address, and then they will bring the plants or seed to the quarantine agency to get treatment and inspection. After that, they will get phytosanitary certificate.

I'm not sure about other countries regulations. But to get the phyto, usually the plants must be taken to a quarantine agency to get treatment and inspection to meet legal requirements in the destination country about importing live plants or seeds.